How does the initial angle of displacement influence the oscillatory damping rate experienced by a simple pendulum?
I suppose increasing the angle of displacement will cause a greater maximum speed achieved by the pendulum at the equilibrium position, and consequently damping.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html

What precisely do you mean by 'damping rate'?
